# Are there any keyboard shortcuts for efficient MIDI (piano roll) editing in Adobe Audition 3?

Tags: midi, editing

I'm aware Audition CS 5.5 is on its way, but this question is about version 3.

It seems such a hassle to switch between the "select" and "draw" tools in the Audition 3 sequencer. There's no hybrid tool (apparently), and if I'm editing a part of a piano roll and just want to move the cursor, I have to get my mouse all the way over to the toolbar and then back. And then again. It really slows me down and drives me nuts.

I couldn't find a way to assign any keyboard shortcuts to these tools. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

From the Audition Help pages:

Choose Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts And MIDI Triggers.

Filter the list of commands as needed:
Select (Show All) or a specific group from the Category menu.
Click the Multitrack, Edit View, and CD View buttons to access commands for each application view.

In the Command Name column, select the command you want to customize.

To assign a keyboard shortcut, click inside the Press New Shortcut Key box, and press the desired key combination.

To remove a keyboard shortcut, click the appropriate Clear button.

Note: If you enter a key combination that’s already in use, Adobe Audition notifies you in the Conflicting Keys box. Click Clear, and enter a different shortcut before continuing.
(Optional) To save a customized shortcut set, click Save As, type a unique name, and click Save.

When you finish making changes, click OK.

Comment: I read the help pages too, and I know about this. However, I can't find anything sequencer-related there. Maybe I'm not looking hard enough, or maybe there's some other place to look, or maybe there's no such option. It's strange if there's no such option, though; have they tried using their own product and realized how clumsy it gets? :)  Thanks nevertheless :)

Comment: I'll try it tonight and report back.